# Javascript URL error for unicode in IE 11

Tags: javascript, php, unicode

i am getting error in internet explorer 11 (IE 11) when i call javascript URL function. The error is url parameter value. The parameter value is in unicode but the result is like this ????? not in unicode. my code below.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(val){
        var val;
        //window.location.assign("index.php?value="+val)
        window.location.href="index.php?value="+val;
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php   
if(!empty($_GET['value'])){
    echo $value=$_GET['value'];
    }
?>
<select style="width:180px;" onchange="test(this.value)">
<option value="">select</option>
<option value="நன்றி">நன்றி</option>
</select>       
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> window.location.href="index.php?value="+val;

URIs can't contain non-ASCII characters. (IRIs can, but what browsers do when presented with them directly is distinctly variable.)

When you put some text into a URI query parameter value, you need to URI-encode it. That's not just because of Unicode—if you don't, then your URI will break for other value characters that are special in URIs, like `&` or `%`.

```
location.href = 'index.php?value=' + encodeURIComponent(val);
```

Asides:

1. Select boxes that auto-navigate, aka “jump lists”, have severe usability/accessibility drawbacks and are almost always better avoided. Consider a pop-up navigation list of real links instead.
2. The `echo $value=$_GET['value'];` debugging line is a cross-site-scripting (XSS) security hole. Always remember to `htmlspecialchars()` all text you output into HTML.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is from your file encoding.
so if you open the file in notepad and past this code
then save it with changing of the file encoding 
to Utf-8
[image: change encoding of the file]

so you will get this result :
[image: result after encoding]

Comment: I have saved my file in UTF-8 format only. still I have error in ie 11 only.